# Simple Form Add title for all inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is it possibe to add title for every input using input names (the same way that it done with labels or placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

You can use title in simple form.

```
<%= f.input :name, input_html: { title: 'Name Input', placeholder: 'Input name here' } %>
```